# Join for every element in the sequense slick 3.3.0

Tags: scala, slick

I have two tables, the first with a column code and the second table with a column of sequence  code.

I want to make a join with every element in the sequence.

[image: this is how the sequence of strings]

How can I achieve this?

Sample of my code:

```
private lazy val withTransco = for {   
 (transco, secteurQuai) <- transcoTable     
      .join(QuaiTable) on ((transco, secteurQuai) => {     
         transco.code === secteurQuai._1.codeSeq   
      }) 
 } yield (transco, secteurQuai)
```

`secteurQuai._1.codeSeq` is a `Rep[Option[String]]`

I'm using scala 2.11.12 and slick 3.3.0

Thanks.

Comment: can you add the sample code?

Comment: `private lazy val withTransco = for {
  (transco, secteurQuai) <- transcoTable
    .join(QuaiTable) on ((transco, secteurQuai) => {
    transco.code === secteurQuai._1.codeSeq
  })
} yield (transco, secteurQuai)`   secteurQuai._1.codeSeq is Rep[Option[String]]